# Clear to end of line uses the wrong background color in screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, colors

In ZSH prompt expansion, the command %E is supposed to "Clear to end of line."

This works. We see it in the grey bar going all the way across.

[image]

However, if I call "screen", the %E stops working:
[image]

Any idea what the cause of this is, and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you send one of the ECMA-48 erase control sequences, whether the erasure uses the *current* background colour or the *default* background colour varies amongst different terminal types.  (In the terminfo database, there is a capability that allows programs to determine what the terminal that they are talking to will do.  It is named `bce`.  The termcap equivalent name is `ut`.)  You are setting the current background colour, and then erasing to the end of the line, *expecting* the erasure to *always* use that current colour.

`screen` is a terminal emulator itself.  But unlike most hardware terminals its behaviour in this regard is switchable.  By default, *background colour erase* is switched off, and the control sequence causes erasure with the default colour.  One switches it on with the `bce` command.  One sets the default for the `bce` setting in all new screens with the `defbce` command.

(I say most, because late model DEC VTs provide DEC Private Mode 117 for switching the behaviour.  The default for these terminals was the "new" PC-compatible behaviour of erasing with the current colour, and switching Private Mode 117 off would revert back to the "old" VT-compatible behaviour of erasing with the default colour.  DEC VT 52x terminals were switchable like `screen`, except that the host could do the switching and the default was the "new" behaviour, the opposite of `screen`'s default.  These terminals were actually newer than `screen`, by several years.)

So switch it on.  It's as simple as that.

## Further reading

- ["Character Processing"](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Character-Processing),  *Screen Users' Manual*.  GNU Project.
- "DECECM". [*VT520/VT525 Video Terminal Programmer Information*](http://web.mit.edu/dosathena/doc/www/ek-vt520-rm.pdf).  EK-VT520-RM.  July 1994.  DEC.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252078/5132

Comment: For anyone reading and who is unfamiliar with .screenrc setup, the exact line is "defbce on"

Comment: The DEC VT520/VT525 manuals are dated July 1994, while the initial copyright for screen is from 1987.  defbce is later, but was not influenced by DEC's terminals.  Whether DECECM actually matches any terminal emulator in use now is indeterminate, since the description can be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: There aren't really multiple ways to interpret §2.9.7 and it isn't ambiguous.