# Clear to end of line uses the wrong background color in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, colors

In ZSH prompt expansion, the command %E is supposed to "Clear to end of line."

This works:
[image]

However, it does not work in tmux:
[image]

The issue seems to be with BCE (Background Color Erase). In screen, I can add the option [defbce on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251726/zsh-and-screen-e-prompt-expansion-not-working/251755#251755). I can't find any similar setting for tmux. Does it exist?

Comment: ensure you are not overriding `TERM=screen` to something else.

Comment: Without tmux TERM is xterm-256. With tmux, TERM is screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unlike `screen`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251755/5132), `tmux` does not have switchable *background colour erase* capability in its terminal emulator.  Erasure is always with the default background colour, never the current background colour.

Nicholas Marriott added it to the to-do list in September 2015, but stated at the time that neither he nor anyone else cares enough about it to implement it.

He later implemented it in October 2016, nearly a year after this answer was originally written.

## Further reading

- Nicholas Marriott (2015-09-15). [*Support background color erase (bce)*](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/109#issuecomment-140371375).  tmux/tmux.  Bug #109.  GitHub.
- Nicholas Marriott (2015-09-15). [*Add BCE to TODO.*](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/54bd7612868341c47bd3bd237c9598d5860b3ef3).  tmux/tmux.  54bd7612868341c47bd3bd237c9598d5860b3ef3.  GitHub.
- [*vim colorscheme completely wrong inside screen or tmux sessions*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511538/5132):

> t_ut turns off BCE. tmux should support BCE but it depends on the tmux version, I think 2.1 is too old.

Comment: looks like [this got fixed roughly in the tmux 2.4 timeframe](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/4179b4242411f41a22d9743b4eff3b19ef69b3e8)