# Invert the color of an entire line in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I understand that the title may seem a little confusing. However, I have an example, GNU Nano. The Nano editor has this one line at the top whose color is totally inverted.[image: Screencap of GNU Nano top bar]Does anyone know how this can be achieved in Bash script?

Comment: @Quasímodo He means the first line: black text on white background looks like "ordinary colors, but inverted".

Comment: @Hermann Thanks, I need to learn to read titles too...

Comment: It looks like you have an application window theming issue, yr app being nano. This seems unrelated to bash per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite easy, you can try this:

```
# Reset
reset='\033[0m'

# White Background
BG='\033[47m'

# Black Foreground
FG='\033[0;30m'

# Usage
echo -e "$FG$BG This will print black text on white background $reset"
```

If you want the whole line:

```
reset='\033[0m'
BG='\033[47m'
FG='\033[0;30m'

text="A black text on white"
cols=$(tput cols)

# Left Aligned
x=$((cols-${#text}))

printf "$FG$BG%s%*s$reset\n" "$text" $x

# Centered text
x_center=$(((${#text}+cols)/2))
x_rest=$((cols-x_center))

printf "$FG$BG%*s%*s$reset\n" $x_center "$text" $x_rest
```

Example output:
[image: black text on white]

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938235/3689465

Comment: @JacobJames Well, you didn't mention it in your question that you need it to be on top of the screen. Otherwise, It might be more trickier. Or maybe a lazy way to do it, do `clear` then print the output, bam! you'll get it on the top of the screen (at least terminal screen).

Comment: @Jaob James: please edit your OQ to fully expose your question. For your information, comments aren't for adding details to the OQ. Moreover, once a question is correctly asked and answered, comments are meant do be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, @annahri!

Comment: [Reverse video is fun.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586458/5132)  There's a reason that programs tend to do what this script does, namely manually swap the colours and print lots of spaces, rather than turn the ECMA-48 reverse video attribute on.  (-: