# Change terminal color set

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, colors

I have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to an E-Ink screen. To make it more readable, I'd like to basically invert all the colors (it is currently white text on black background, I'd like black text on white background).  I can use X11 and a window manager, but I'd really like to make it light weight and just use tmux in the linux terminal as my interface.

So basically, I want to make the background of the linux terminal white and the foreground black.

I've tried escape sequences, LS_COLORS, and tput but all those seem to only affect the parts of the screen that have text, so the parts of the screen that are blank end up black. I looked at (but did not try) [PaperTTY](https://github.com/joukos/PaperTTY) but I would like to work with the linux terminal rather than a terminal emulator.

I'm not sure how to go about this, but it seems like I need to adjust a more low level setting so that something like `tput setab 0` would result in a white background (or something like that).

If it affects anything, I am on [Arch Arm](https://archlinuxarm.org/) and bash.

Comment: You might have some luck with `setterm --inversescreen on`, but see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586458/119298).

Comment: @meuh That worked perfect, if you want to put it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. The reference was really helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a long detailed [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586458/119298) about this subject by **JdeBP** from which the salient point is that you should be able to give the command

```
setterm --inversescreen on
```

in many terminals on Linux to set the "DECSCNM (DEC Screen Mode)" to *whole screen inverse video*.