# Change terminal color theme to black ink on white paper in Q4OS

Tags: terminal, colors, theme

I am using the Q4OS linux.
The terminal has a dark theme with black background and white ink.
I would like to have black ink on white background in the terminal.
I have found a partial solution by modifying $PS1.
It is not satisfactory because for example `nano` still uses the dark theme.

I have read [Change terminal color set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617551/change-terminal-color-set) giving the advice to run `setterm --inversescreen on` and it is almost the thing I am trying to achieve but if you look at the attached screenshot you will notice that the background is not really white, it is rather gray.

Hopefully, there is a systematic solution to have a really white background with dark text and the rest of the theme suitably matching.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by installing a newer version of Q4OS. Now the terminal window has a Settings tab which allows me to choose the theme I want.

Comment: What version number. Please [edit] your answer and add that info, it could be useful for others.